# How can i identity contacts in memory wise?

Tags: 8.0, contacts

How can i identify a  contact whether it belongs to  sim memory or phone memory? Also what is the default storage location for newly created contacts?(on my hand :Lumia 525,8.0) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Phone does not let you manually save contacts to the SIM card. Any contacts you add will be saved to one of your online accounts (by default, your Microsoft account). You can only [import contacts from a SIM card](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-gb/how-to/wp8/people/import-contacts-from-my-old-phone).

> How can i identify a contact whether it belongs to sim memory or phone memory?

If the contact shows up in the People app, it's not on the SIM card.

> Also what is the default storage location for newly created contacts?

Phone memory. Or, more specifically, an online account synced to your phone.

Answer (score -2):

> How can i identify a contact whether it belongs to sim memory or phone memory?

You cannot identify that. If your contacts are stored in your SIM then you need to import them to the phone.

**To import contacts from your SIM**

> 1. On **Start** [image], tap **People** [image].
> 2. Tap **More** [image], then tap **Settings**.
> 3. Tap **Import from SIM.** If you have more than one SIM card, select the one you want under **Import contacts from.**
> 4. Under **Save contacts to**, select the account you'd like to store the contacts in, then tap **Next**.
> 5. Do one of the following:
>
> - To import all of the contacts on your SIM card, tap **Import**.
> - If you want to select contacts to import individually, tap **Clear**, select the contacts you want to import, then tap **Import**.
>
> *Note: To import SIM contacts individually, your phone must be running Windows Phone software version 8.0.10211.204 or later.*

Source: [Importing contacts from your old phone](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-phone-8-1-end-of-support-faq-7f1ef0aa-0aaf-0747-3724-5c44456778a3)

---

**Default Storage Location**

> Also what is the default storage location for newly created contacts?

Just searched some forums and I got the answer from [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/q-how-to-save-import-contacts-to-sim-card.1629952/#post-25551728).

The default storage location for newly created contacts will be in Phone only. Windows Phone does not provide the feature to save contact in SIM.

> If you have more than one account on your phone, you'll have a chance to choose which one to save the contact in. Do one of the following:
>
> - If this is the first time you've created a contact, tap the account you want to use. This will be your default account—where your new contacts will be saved from now on.
> - If this isn't your first new contact, you can change the default account and save the contact to a different account. Just tap **Save to**, then choose the account you want. This will be your new default account, until you change it again.

Source: [Create and edit my contacts](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-phone-8-1-end-of-support-faq-7f1ef0aa-0aaf-0747-3724-5c44456778a3)

Comment: Thanks for the edit. But I guess I forgot to answer "How can i identify a contact whether it belongs to sim memory or phone memory?" :)

Comment: The way I understand it, "default storage location" in the question refers to phone memory vs. SIM, not the various online accounts, so you haven't answered that question either.

Comment: Please see updated answer.